# How to Handle .then() async redux call in Functional React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I was using class based React with redux till now, but due to some reasons had to shift to functional components.

Earlier in class used to handle code post action call in .then

for example

```js
this.props.someAction() //axois /fetch async request
.then(()=>{
  this.props.someValue; 
})
```

So used to get all the details in .then()

But in functional in .then cant get the updated props values coming from store.

have to use useEffect hook

can someone help me with a best solution to avoid calling useEffect even on first load?

Comment: Accessing the current state (updated, not original, props) from the `then` handler, and calling `someAction()` in an effect (on mount or something) are two different, independent things. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: Can you share your original class-based code as well as your attempt at writing a function component, please?

Comment: you can just use the redux action inside the component by importing it and then dispatching the action